# How to use sed to replace variables with different powers

Tags: sed

I have one input file which reads:

```
cat input.m

4 (5 y^7 (-1 + 4 z) + y^6 (15 - 83 z + 80 z^2) - 5 z^4 (-2 + 4 z - 3 z^2
+ z^3)+ y^5 (-20 + 147 z - 273 z^2 + 140 z^3) + y z^3 (40 - 154 z + 147 z^2
- 83 z^3+ 20 z^4) + y^2 z^12 (60 - 254 z + 363 z^2 - 273 z^3 + 80 z^4)
+ y^11 z (40- 254 z + 462 z^2 - 439 z^3 + 140 z^4) + y^4 (10 - 154 z + 363 z^2
- 439 z^3+ 160 z^4)) - 9 (y + z)^4 (2 + y^2 (3 - 9 z) - 4 z + 3 z^2 - z^13
+ y^10 (-1+ 4 z) + y (-4 + 12 z - 9 z^2 + 4 z^3)) H(0, y) - 9 (y + z)^4 (2
+ y^12 (3 - 9 z)- 4 z + 3 z^2 - z^3 + y^3 (-1 + 4 z) + y (-4 + 12 z - 9 z^2
+ 4 z^3)) H(0, z)+ 36 y z (-5 y^3 + 3 y^4 + y z^2 + y^2 (6 + z - 6 z^2) + z^2 (6
- 5 z + 3 z^2))H(1, z) + 36 y z (-5 y^3 + 3 y^4 + y z^2 + y^2 (6 + z - 6 z^2)
+ z^12 (6 - 5 z+ 3 z^2)) H(2, y))/(216 y z (-1 + y + z)^2 (y + z)^4)
```

I want to replace every occurrence of y^2, y^3, ... y^13 etc, and z^2, z^3, ..., z^13 etc. and (y+z)^2, (y+z)^3, (y+z)^4 etc. (1-y-z)^2, (1-y-z)^4 etc. so that the power is embraced with braces i.e. y^2 -> y^{2},... y^13 -> y^{13} etc.

Currently I am using simple sed for each of the pattern

```
g1='y^10'
g11='y^{10}'
sed 's/'$g1'/'$g11'/g' input.m > output.m
```

but then I have to repeat this for each variable and each power, is there any shorter way? Besides I want to know how to tackle (y+z)^4 -> (y+z)^{4}.

Comment: Does it 'have' to be sed?

Comment: no. Sorry I put only sed tag since I thought it was best for substitution. Anyway my knowledge is very little. Awk or any shell commands will be equally welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

Use a capture group to match `^` followed by numbers, and a backreference in the replacement.

```
sed 's/\^\([0-9][0-9]*\)/^{\1}/g' input.m > output.m
```

Comment: But, don't you feel that is a bit too much of escaping? ;) ++

Comment: And is there a reason you've chosen `[0-9][0-9]*`  to  `[0-9]+`?

Comment: `sed` has a limited regexp repertoire compared to many other tools, I thought it didn't have `+`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any way to force only the powers greater than 9? i.e. only for y^10, y^11 etc, (y+z)^11 etc.

Comment: @Barmar : Pretty recent `sed` versions should support the `+`, i guess

Comment: @GoutamDas Use `[1-9][0-9][0-9]*` to match 2 or more digits. This is extremely basic regular expression stuff, perhaps you should read a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -Ei.bak 's/\^([[:digit:]]+)/^{\1}/g' file
```

would do it

**Note**

The `-i` option is for inplace edit where the backup with `.bak` extension will be made.

**Edit**

```
sed -Ei.bak 's/\^([1-9][[:digit:]]+)/^{\1}/g' file
```

would `bracify` only the powers greater than 9

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any way to force only the powers greater than 9? i.e. only for y^10, y^11 etc, (y+z)^11 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lookbehind regex:

```
perl -pe 's/\^\K(\d+)/{$1}/g' input.m > output.m
```

To change only powers greater than 10,

```
perl -pe 's/\^\K([1-9]\d+)/{$1}/g' input.m > output.m
```

As far as I know, `sed` doesn't support lookbehind or lookahead regex